# When is componentWillLoad called in stencil.js?

Tags: stenciljs

So for example if I have component parent and component child, and initially parent gives a certain value for a @Prop annotated field of component child, and then a new different one, will componentWillLoad run 2 times for componentChild (is it attached to the DOM 2 times)?

It seems like it is attached to the DOM 2 times, because componentWillLoad is run again once the @Prop annotated field changes.

Comment: Without knowing what your code actually looks like, it's kind of difficult to provide any assistance.  Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.